# C++ windows API GetSecurityInfo invalid handle given

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, registry

I'm trying to create a new registry key in Windows 10 using the Windows API, namely the `RegCreateKeyEx` function, and then get its DACL  using `GetSecurityInfo`. All the asserts go smoothly until i get to said `GetSecurityInfo` function call, which gives an invalid handle value error(error 6). What am I doing wrong?

This is part of a more elaborate project so I will only give the(or what I think it is, but i can add the rest too) relevant part here:

A wrapper to `RegCreateKeyEx` to make the output easier to work with and set any errors encountered:

```
inline extern auto RegCreateKeyEx_safe(
    _In_       const HKEY                  hKey,
    _In_       const LPCTSTR               lpSubKey,
    _Reserved_ const DWORD                 Reserved,
    _In_opt_   const LPTSTR                lpClass,
    _In_       const DWORD                 dwOptions,
    _In_       const REGSAM                samDesired,
    _In_opt_   const LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    _Out_      const PHKEY                 phkResult,
    _Out_opt_  const LPDWORD               lpdwDisposition)
{
    const auto result = 
        RegCreateKeyEx(
            hKey,
            lpSubKey,
            Reserved,
            lpClass,
            dwOptions,
            samDesired,
            lpSecurityAttributes,
            phkResult,
            lpdwDisposition);
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        SetLastError(result);
    return result == ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

A wrapper to the above function that should return a handle to the created key after checking if it is valid:

```
inline extern auto CreateNewRegKey(
    HKEY                  hKey,
    LPCTSTR               lpSubKey,
    DWORD                 Reserved,
    LPTSTR                lpClass,
    DWORD                 dwOptions,
    REGSAM                samDesired,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    LPDWORD               lpdwDisposition)
{
    auto createdKey = static_cast<PHKEY>(malloc(sizeof HKEY));

    assert(
        RegCreateKeyEx_safe(
            hKey,
            lpSubKey,
            Reserved,
            lpClass,
            dwOptions,
            samDesired,
            lpSecurityAttributes,
            createdKey,
            lpdwDisposition));

    assert(createdKey != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    return createdKey;
}
```

And a wrapper for `GetSecurityInfo`, same reason and functionality as the `RegCreateKey` version:

```
inline extern auto GetSecurityInfo_safe(
    _In_      const HANDLE                handle,
    _In_      const SE_OBJECT_TYPE        ObjectType,
    _In_      const SECURITY_INFORMATION  SecurityInfo,
    _Out_opt_       PSID*                 ppsidOwner,
    _Out_opt_       PSID*                 ppsidGroup,
    _Out_opt_       PACL*                 ppDacl,
    _Out_opt_       PACL*                 ppSacl,
    _Out_opt_       PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR* ppSecurityDescriptor)
{
    const auto result =
        GetSecurityInfo(
            handle,
            ObjectType,
            SecurityInfo,
            ppsidOwner,
            ppsidGroup,
            ppDacl,
            ppSacl,
            ppSecurityDescriptor);
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        SetLastError(result);
    return result == EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now the code calling these functions is as follows:

```
 const auto newRegKey = 
        CreateNewRegKey(
            HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
            SUBKEY_PATH, 
            NULL, 
            nullptr, 
            REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, 
            KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 
            NULL,  //securityAttributes, 
            nullptr);

    assert(
        GetSecurityInfo_safe(
            newRegKey,
            SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
            DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            oldDacl,
            NULL,
            NULL));
```

The output is pretty clear on where the issue is(I implemented a slightly more verbose assert that after checking the condition, it prints it, along with the error text in case the condition failed):

```
SUCCESS:        RegCreateKeyEx_safe( hKey, lpSubKey, Reserved, lpClass, dwOptions, samDesired, lpSecurityAttributes, createdKey, lpdwDisposition)
SUCCESS:        createdKey != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
FAILURE:        GetSecurityInfo_safe( newRegKey, SE_REGISTRY_KEY, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, oldDacl, NULL, NULL)

ERROR-6:        The handle is invalid.
```

The assert:

```
#define _VERBOSE            (1)
#define assert(cond)        if((cond) == TRUE) \
                                { if (_VERBOSE) cout << "SUCCESS:\t" << #cond << endl; } \
                            else \
                                {cout << "FAILURE:\t" << #cond << "\n\nERROR-" << GetLastError() << ":\t" << GetLastErrorAsString() << "\n\n"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is sense in this wrappers which make work only harder ? and `SetLastError` not need here - the Reg api just return error code instead true/false, which really much more better design and easy to use

Comment: @RbMm they are needed as the code is part of a more elaborate project, and consistency, makes it much easier to work with bigger codebases :)

Comment: work with function which return error code - much more easy than with function which return true/false and set last error

Comment: Some functions from the Windwes API use the "classic" way of returning an error code and others return a winapi BOOL, there is no inherent consistency, so i had to hack it in myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `CreateNewRegKey` is returning a *pointer* to an `HKEY` where it should return `HKEY` by value. You pass this pointer to `GetSecurityInfo()` which expects a `HANDLE` instead. The compiler won't notice because `HANDLE` is declared as `typedef void *HANDLE;`.

To correct the error replace:

> ```
> auto createdKey = static_cast<PHKEY>(malloc(sizeof HKEY));
> ```

with

```
HKEY createdKey = NULL;
```

and call `RegCreateKeyEx_safe()` with `&createdKey` to pass the address of the `HKEY`.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to force myself to work mostly/only with pointers, auto variables and the such to get a better feel for them so I actually fixed it it by dereferencing newRegKey in the `GetSecurityInfo` function call: 
`GetSecurityInfo_safe(
            *newRegKey,
            SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
            ...`
But I would not have noticed that without your help, thanks again!